# cant seem to move image

Tags: html, css, position, responsive

I am trying to move my image a bit up to align with the x axis but i have tried position relative and padding but it doesnt seem to move but when i change width it works. I am making the change in .luxxreno img but it is not working does anyone know why and how i will adjust its position? I just want to move it up a bit because it is not aligned in my div/

CSS

```
.container {
  padding: 2.5em 1.25em 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-bottom: 0.125em solid rgb(105, 105, 105);
  border-width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 1.25em;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.125em;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1;
  color: white;
}
h1 span {
  display: block;
  animation: reveal 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.5s;
}

.meet-the-owner h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 215, 0);
  font-size: 1.5625em;
  font-family: "BatmanForeverAlternate";
}
.meet-the-owner-top h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 215, 0);
  font-size: 1.5625em;
  font-family: "BatmanForeverAlternate";
  padding: 2.5em;
}

.luxxreno {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 2.5em;
}

.luxxreno img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 3em;
}

.meet-the-owner {
  padding: 3.125em;
  border-top: 0.125em solid rgb(105, 105, 105);
}
.q-l {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-top: 2em;
}

.questions p {
  padding: 0.625em;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
.luxx-name {
  font-family: "BatmanForeverAlternate";
  left: 0.2em;
  font-size: 3.125em;
  top: 1.9em;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.owner {
  font-family: "BatmanForeverAlternate";
  color: red;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
.luxx-socials {
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

HTML

```
<section class="player-bios">

      <div class="container">
        <h1>
            <span>Players</span>
        </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="meet-the-owner-top">

    <h3>Meet the Owner</h3>

  </div>

  <div class="luxxreno">

    <img src="images/luxx.jpg">
    <div class="q-l">
    <div class="questions">
      <h2 class="luxx-name">LUXX RENO</h2>
      <h2 class="owner">OWNER</h2>
      <p>Real Name: <b>Cory George</b></p>
      <p>Online Name: <b>Luxx Reno</b></p>
      <p>First Game Played as a Kid: <b>Duck Hunter/Super Nintendo</b></p>
      <p>Game I'm Best At: <b>Fortnite</b></p>
      <p>If You Were a Superhero, What Would Your Power Be?: <br><b>Mimicry, so I'd be able to mimic and super power I see.</b></p>
      <p>Favourite Artist of All Time: <b>Billy Raffoul</b></p>
      <p>Hidden Talents: <b>Won lots of medals for swimming!</b></p>
    </div>

  <div class="luxx-socials">
<ul>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPqsHNuWTAbckHg4R3WAJIg" target=”_blank”><li>487 @ YouTube</li></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/luxxreno/?hl=en" target=”_blank”><li>2.6k @ Instagram</li></a>
    <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/luxxreno" target=”_blank”><li>3k @ Twitch</li></a><br>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/LuxxReno" target=”_blank”><li>2.5k @ Twitter</li></a>
    <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@luxxxreno?lang=en&is_copy_url=1&is_from_webapp=v1" target=”_blank”><li>657k @ TikTok</li></a>
</ul>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>

  <div class="meet-the-owner">

    <h3>Content Creator</h3>

  </div>

  <div class="luxxreno">

    <img src="images/abz-c.png">
    <div class="q-l">
    <div class="questions">
      <h2 class="luxx-name">ABZZINO</h2>
      <h2 class="owner">Content Creator</h2>
      <p>Real Name: <b>Abdullah Khan</b></p>
      <p>Online Name: <b>Abzzino</b></p>
      <p>First Game Played as a Kid: <b>Call Of Duty</b></p>
      <p>Game I'm Best At: <b>Call Of Duty (all of them)</b></p>
      <p>If You Were a Superhero, What Would Your Power Be?: <br> <b>Flying</b></p>
      <p>Hidden Talents: <b>They're hidden for a reason.</b></p>
    </div>

  <div class="luxx-socials">
<ul>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/c/Abzzino/featured" target=”_blank”><li>360 @ YouTube</li></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/_abzzino_/" target=”_blank”><li>193 @ Instagram</li></a>
    <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/abzzinok" target=”_blank”><li>2.6k @ Twitch</li></a><br>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/_Abzzino_" target=”_blank”><li>142 @ Twitter</li></a>
    <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@abzzinoyt?lang=en" target=”_blank”><li>23.6k @ TikTok</li></a>
</ul>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>

  <div class="meet-the-owner">

    <h3>COMPETITIVE PLAYER</h3>

  </div>

  <div class="luxxreno">

    <img src="images/kyran-c.png">
    <div class="q-l">
    <div class="questions">
      <h2 class="luxx-name">KEEZO</h2>
      <h2 class="owner">COMPETITIVE PLAYER</h2>
      <p>Real Name: <b>Kyran Garden</b></p>
      <p>Online Name: <b>KEEZO</b></p>
      <p>First Game Played as a Kid: <b>Call Of Duty 3</b></p>
      <p>Game I'm Best At: <b>Warzone</b></p>
      <p>If You Were a Superhero, What Would Your Power Be?: <br> <b>Flying</b></p>
      <p>Favourite Artist of All Time: <b>Drake</b></p>
      <p>Hidden Talents: <b>I'm good at football.</b></p>
    </div>

  <div class="luxx-socials">
<ul>
    <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/LKeezo" target=”_blank”><li>400 @ Twitch</li></a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/KEEZZ0" target=”_blank”><li>1.2k @ Twitter</li></a>
    <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@kkeezo?lang=en" target=”_blank”><li>1.1k @ TikTok</li></a>
</ul>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>

  <div class="meet-the-owner">

    <h3>Content Manager</h3>

  </div>

  <div class="luxxreno">

    <img src="images/brad-c.png">
    <div class="q-l">
    <div class="questions">
      <h2 class="luxx-name">SPODERBRAD</h2>
      <h2 class="owner">Content Manager</h2>
      <p>Real Name: <b>Brad</b></p>
      <p>Online Name: <b>SpoderBrad</b></p>
      <p>First Game Played as a Kid: <b>Metal Gear Solid</b></p>
      <p>Game I'm Best At: <b>Splitgate</b></p>
      <p>If You Were a Superhero, What Would Your Power Be?: <br><b>Honestly don’t want a super power just wanna <br> be Iron Man.</b></p>
      <p>Favourite Artist of All Time: <br> <b>Drake or Eminem can’t decide</b></p>
      <p>Hidden Talents: <b>Best Free Kick Taker on Twitch.</b></p>
    </div>

  <div class="luxx-socials">
<ul>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnqgXWWmmg1F3L919lzT6aQ" target=”_blank”><li>353 @ YouTube</li></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/spoderbrad/?hl=en-gb" target=”_blank”><li>115 @ Instagram</li></a>
    <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/SpoderBrad" target=”_blank”><li>2.1k @ Twitch</li></a><br>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/SpoderBrad" target=”_blank”><li>392 @ Twitter</li></a>
    <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@spoderbrad?lang=en" target=”_blank”><li>60k @ TikTok</li></a>
</ul>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>

    </section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not absolutely certain that this is what you are talking about, but in this CSS

```
.luxxreno img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 3em;
}
```

the top setting will be ignored because there is no position set on the element. And when you do set it, make sure whatever ancestor element you want it positioned relative to also has a position set, otherwise CSS will hunt up the DOM til it finds such an ancestor.

Comment: thank you this worked i can change my position but do you know how i will change size because i am using width: 400px and no change is happening.

Comment: This may be a different question, but for now let me know where you are changing the width.

Comment: i want to change size of the image, i am using .luxxreno img

Comment: Have a look n your browser's dev tools to see exactly what CSS stying is being applied to the image - this should show you why your 400px is getting overwritten if it is